# Collecting Performance metrics of Java application interacting with several AWS services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, performance-testing, microbenchmark

I want to get the performance metrics of a Java application that interacts with several AWS services using the AWS Java SDK. I am not sure how to approach this task, for context - my application can be considered as a client sending and receiving requests and responses to/fro AWS. I have looked at several options e.g. ELK APM: it seems that the measurements are based on the number of requests against my application (or other metrics) from other applications, but my application is not a server. I am at evaluating the number of requests (or other metrics) directly against the AWS services from my application. I also considered using tools provided by AWS e.g. CloudWatch, however, it seems this approach ends up testing the performance of those AWS services rather than my application. Lastly, I am considering using Apache JMeter, but I am not sure if it will serve the purpose, the diagram below illustrates my question. I will appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

**Update**: I want to monitor the performance, I am using VisualVM for monitoring CPU, memory etc. I need a way to monitor requests and responses.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to monitor performance or do performance testing?

Comment: I want to monitor the performance, I am using VisualVM for monitoring CPU, memory etc. I need a way to monitor the requests and responses.

Comment: Then you might want to look at monitoring frameworks such as Dropwizard.

Comment: RIght, will have a look at DropWizard.

Answer (score 0):

1. For performance testing of the application itself you need to use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
2. If you need to test the performance of the AWS services you can simulate hundreds/thousands of applications using Apache JMeter (or any other suitable tool), you just need to simulate the requests which your application is normally sending using JMeter. If the communication is being done using HTTP or HTTPS protocols you can even record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/) article for more details.